# what is the Problems with this regexes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have name  ( fname+lname) and email and i have their regexes but they are not validating

```
var  fnlnregex = /^[\w\/\s\.-]+$/;  //first name + last name   
var usremailregex = /^[@.\w]+$/;

if(!usremailregex.test($("#Eml").val())){
        flag = false;
        $("#Eml").attr('class','red');  
    }else{
        $("#Eml").attr('class','');
    }
```

But it is not validating the email field  it is taking the following data as correct 
    //if i enter only "abc" in the email field it is not taking as wrong

fnlnregex - this should not allow numbers but in my same if for name regex it is allowing . How do i correct the 
two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[@.\w]+$/` means:

`start of string - one or more of a combination of @, any character or word boundary - end of string`

I must say that it's pretty useless. The `.` means any character which includes `@` and `\w` already.

As for why `abc` matches - well, it matches `beginning - any character - end`.

What you're looking for is something along the lines of:

`/^[a-z0-9]+@[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]+$/i`

which translates to:

`beginning - one or more letters or digits - a @ - one or more letters or digits - a . - one or more letters - end`.

The `i` means that it's case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

your usremailreg will never work to validate emails. It accepts anything that has at least ONE character that's a `.`, a `@`, or `a-z0-9A-Z`. so `@@@@@@@@@` is perfectly valid.

Try this one on for size to validate RFC822-compliant addresses:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

Answer (score 0):

usremailregex: if the string consists only of '@', '.', or word characters, allow it. That is valid for abc.

Comment: Looks like Marc B gave the more complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the first regex you're using the \w shorthand, which matches any word character, including numbers; you could try with:

```
/^[A-Za-z\/\s\.-]+$/
```

if you just want alphabetical characters.